# Как правильно выполнить запрос перед закртием/загрузкой другой страницы?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Перед переходом на другую страницу или когда пользователь принудительно закрывает вкладку браузера необходим передать на сервер некоторые данные. 
Отправку выполняю POST запросом.
В Chrom работает, хотя были случаи, когда этот запрос не выполнялся.
В Firefox запрос вообще не выполняется.
Сделал запрос синхоронным.
Работает везде.
Но правильно ли его выполнять синхронно?
Какие еще могут быть решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Специально для таких случаев придумали [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon).

```
window.addEventListener("unload", logData, false);

function logData() {
  navigator.sendBeacon("/log", analyticsData);
}
```

Поддержка более-менее [хорошая](https://caniuse.com/#search=sendBeacon).

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов, выполнять регулярные запросы, типа Alive, как только доступ пропал, значит вкладка типа закрыта, правда тут не отследить случай обрыва сети